# synchronising endpoint addresses between angular and asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, angularjs

I am exposing some JSON endpoints (using ASP.NET MVC 3 rather than ASP.NET web api), which are consumed by angular. Is there a way to avoid hard coding endpoint addresses in the js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Hypermedia` style API.

The idea is to use a resource API to return the available endpoints in the format of a *slug* which is the flag of the API and the *URL* to the API).

```
{
    resources: [{
        name: "service1",
        url: "http://localhost/myservice/1"
    }, {
        name: "service2",
        url: "http://localhost/myservice/registerinfo"
    }]
}
```

The good part of this, is you can easily control the availability of the APIs based on some permissions/roles.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just to clarify. My understanding is that a hypermedia/hateoas restful web service has one (entry) endpoint. Are you saying that the above information is obtained from there (i.e. where all the other required services are)? Thanks.

Comment: @csetzkorn Yes. You can make the above info in the entry API.

Comment: so server side there would be one method called resources that spews out the above JSON? Thanks.